# Proper use for TextUtils.commaEllipsize

Tags: android, android-layout, textutils

I'm looking for some sample code on how to use this correctly with a `TextView`.

the only thing I found in my Google searching was this [test unit for the TextUtils class](http://gitorious.org/freebroid/cts/blobs/7745fc6a9ead88802ca58160c66a43b3ea062927/tests/tests/text/src/android/text/cts/TextUtilsTest.java).

some guidance will be much appreciated.

***EDIT:***

I looked over the answer I got here and tried to implement it on my code. I used this code snippet:

```
    TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listitemThreadsTitle);
    title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    TextPaint p = title.getPaint();
    String strTitle = "Moe, Joe, Isaac, Bethany, Cornelius, Charlie";
    title.setText(strTitle);
    float avail = p.measureText(strTitle);
    CharSequence ch = TextUtils.commaEllipsize(strTitle, p, avail, "one more", "%d more");
    title.setText(ch);
```

but the result was absolutely not what it's supposed to be.

it was more like: Moe, Joe, Isaac, Betha...

instead of: Moe, Joe, Isaac + 3

Comment: Have you refered documentation ? Its quite simple...

Comment: @userSeven7s, I have. didn't quite understand how to correctly measure the space for the `avail` parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static CharSequence commaEllipsize (CharSequence text, TextPaint p, 
                                       float avail, String oneMore, String more)
```

### Parameters:

**text**    - the text to truncate
**p**       - the Paint with which to measure the text
**avail**   - the horizontal width available for the text
**oneMore** - the string for "1 more" in the current locale
**more**    - the string for "%d more" in the current locale

### Example Usage:

```
String text = "Apple, Orange, Mango, Banana";
TextView tv = new TextView(context);
float textWidth = tv.getPaint().measureText(text );
String tempStr = TextUtils.commaEllipsize(text, tv.getPaint(), textWidth, 
                                           "1 more", "%d more");
tv.setText(tempStr);
```

Update:

```
TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listitemThreadsTitle);
title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

TextPaint p = title.getPaint();
String strTitle = "Moe, Joe, Isaac, Bethany, Cornelius, Charlie";
title.setText(strTitle);
float avail = title.getMeasuredWidth();
CharSequence ch = TextUtils.commaEllipsize(strTitle, p, avail, "one more", "%d more");
title.setText(ch);
```

Comment: well, how do I check the textwidth? I have the the TextView tv. should I use `tv.getPaint(). measureText(text)`?

Comment: well, I tried using `tv.getPaint().measureText(text)`, but this is not working properly, I get a 0 result from this, meaning that there is no Elipsis happening. how can I measure the available size I have for the text?

Comment: Use `title.getMeasuredWidth()` for getting the avail value.. Assuming the `title` width is set to match_parent..

Comment: this didn't work :( ended up writing a primitive function to do this myself

Comment: then get the title's parent width into avail.. `title.getParent().getWidth()` or `title.getParent().getMeasuredWidth()`

Comment: `avail = parent width - icon width`.. avail is the max width available for the textview in its parent..